# App is crashing after APK build is generated from EXPO

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo

My app crashed, it couldn't work after being built. I looked at the logcat on Android studio and it seems there is a conflict between "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.15" and "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.24". Here is my app.js file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crdm7.png)

Comment: Hey there, not a react expert, so I cannot help with your question, but as a tip to get good answers in future: Do not include code as screenshot into your question, because a) one needs to click an unmarked link to a different site and its not visible immediately, and b) because its hard to extract code to reproduce the issue or add to an answer. Instead, use the code formatting options and add your source code as text to your question

Answer (score 0):

There could be 2 possible reasons;

1. You are not generating the debug/release APK correctly.
2. App is encountering some error and you are not handling it properly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).